# Mercurial vs Git in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, mercurial, intellij-idea

Regarding IntelliJ IDEA 12 (or the new 13 Beta, but please specify which), which integration is better, the one with GIT or the one with Mercurial, and why?

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains uses Git as their VCS. It is more likely to get the latest fixes since they are dogfooding. Mercurial support is good, but gets less attention.

Comment: I wouldn't call mercurial support good. It is really miles behind the mercurial plugin for eclipse for instance. I'd say if you use IntelliJ you're pretty much going to have to use an external tool to handle your mercurial versioning.

Comment: I do use TortoiseHG as well. But I like the integration with IntelliJ tasks and the pre-checkin code inspections.

Comment: Well those are nice, but they aren't really specific to the handling of Mercurial. The integration with is missing a lot of useful functionality, such as listing incoming and outgoing changesets, the history graph, rebase, graft, inline diff, etc... IntelliJ has many strengths, but version control is not one of them.